# Can I only update a specific property within a data object?

Tags: svelte

I'm creating a rudimentary chessboard, and in my `data`, I have an object of pieces:

```
data() {
  return {
    pieces: {
      id3: { ...piece },
      id4: { ...piece },
      etc.
    }
  }
}
```

What I'd like to do, is to only update a specific piece, rather than creating a new pieces object and updating all of them. So I want to do:

```
this.set({ pieces[id4]: { ... });
```

rather than:

```
const new pieces = {...};

this.set({ pieces });
```

Is there any way to do this in SvelteJS?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that and then some more using [svelte-extras](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-extras).

For your case you need `setDeep(keypath, value)` - [description](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-extras#setdeepkeypath-value-live-demo) and [live demo](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.60.0&gist=e33d01f9796341992101d8c23070eb76).